# How to select adjacent columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

**My table:** `vocabulary`

```
    id          word
--------------------------
    1           hello
    2           hello
    3           how
    4           how
    5           how
    6           are
    7           hello
    8           hello
    9           are
    10          are
    11          are
    12          are
    13          hello
```

I want to `select id from vocabulary where id=$id and {all rows that are both the same word and adjacent}`

> **Note:** I want both of them: [id=$id] and [all rows that are both the same word and adjacent]

In fact, I need to a `SELECT` query to do something like this: *(three examples)*

1. `$id=1`, result: **1,2** // [1 for `$id=1`] - [2 for the word of 1 and 2 are the same and adjacent]
2. `$id=6`, result: **6** // [6 for `$id=6`]
3. `$id=10`,result: **9,10,11,12** // [10 for`$id=10`]-[9,11,12  for the word of 10 is the same with 9,11,12]

Comment: This is a 'sequence starts and ends' problem

Comment: what is that mean? is it impossible ?

Comment: No. It means you now know what to google.

Comment: aha :) I google it very much,but i can not solve it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution using variables:

```
SELECT id, word
FROM (
  SELECT id,       
         @rnk:= CASE WHEN @word = word THEN @rnk 
                   ELSE @rnk + 1
              END AS rnk,
         @word:= word AS word
  FROM vocabulary, (SELECT @rnk:=0) as vars    
  ORDER BY id ) s
WHERE s.rnk = (
    SELECT rnk
    FROM (
      SELECT id,       
             @r:= CASE WHEN @w = word THEN @r 
                       ELSE @r + 1
                  END AS rnk,
             @w:= word AS word
      FROM vocabulary, (SELECT @r:=0) as vars    
      ORDER BY id ) t
    WHERE id = 10) -- 10 is equal to $id
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e6b9d/32)

The same query is repeated two times, due to lack of `CTE`s in MySQL. `@rnk` and `@r` variables are used to identify islands of continuous `word` values within `vocabulary` table.

The second query picks the island value (e.g. `@r = 5` for `id = 10`) and the first one uses this value to select all records that belong to the same island.

Comment: Can you give a brief description ?

Comment: @stack I think I did give a short description. You can try executing separately one of the subqueries to see what it returns. You will then realize that `@r`, `@rnk` variables have the same value for all records that belong to the same group of values, also called an island.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic pattern that you can adapt to your purpose...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,word VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,'hello'),
(2 ,'hello'),
(3 ,'how'),
(4 ,'how'),
(5 ,'how'),
(6 ,'are'),
(7 ,'hello'),
(8 ,'hello'),
(9 ,'are'),
(10,'are'),
(11,'are'),
(12,'are'),
(13,'hello');

SELECT a.id start
     , MIN(c.id) end 
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.id = a.id - 1
   AND b.word = a.word
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table c 
    ON c.id >= a.id
   AND c.word = a.word
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table d 
    ON d.id = c.id + 1
   AND d.word = a.word
 WHERE b.id IS NULL 
   AND c.id IS NOT NULL
   AND d.id IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.id; 

+-------+------+
| start | end  |
+-------+------+
|     1 |    2 |
|     3 |    5 |
|     6 |    6 |
|     7 |    8 |
|     9 |   12 |
|    13 |   13 |
+-------+------+
```

As McAdam331 suggests, one way of extending this idea is as follows:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM vocabulary 
  JOIN tmpTable 
 WHERE id BETWEEN tmpTable.start AND tmpTable.end 
  AND tmpTable.start = $id;
```

Comment: em .. Honestly i dont got it ..! :( I did your code on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and checked result, but i don't know how should i use it for myself ..?

Comment: @stack now that you know the start and end sequences, you can do something like: `SELECT * FROM vocabulary JOIN tmpTable WHERE id BETWEEN tmpTable.start AND tmpTable.end AND tmpTable.start = $id;`. That's just rough psuedocode.

Comment: aha, i think i got it a little bit :) !!! @McAdam331 may put your suggestion as a new answer ? ( thoroughly :) )

Comment: My suggestion is not a new answer, just a continuation of Strawberry's. It's up to him if he feels like adding it on to his answer, as anyone can come along and read the comments anyways.

Comment: @McAdam331 at least edit Strawberry's answer and add your suggestion.  Because i don't know how to use of your suggestion and this answer together ...!

Comment: This isn't my answer to edit, I was just giving you another nudge in the right direction. Take some time to think about it and you should be able to get the answer. Think about how you would do it, write the steps on pen and paper if you have to, and then try to write the query.